# XSS encode / decode strange char interpretation

Tags: xss

Can anyone tell me why I can't get this XSS to reflect? Or why is this Filtered or not rendering?

The Post sent is:

```
...
Content-Length: 91

add=1&reference=A</><img src=a onalert=alert(1)>EXPXSS&name=example&group=EE%2FBB&x=68&y=19
```

The response:

```
<td><a class="remove" href="index.xml?action=remove&#38;ref=A&lt;/&gt;&lt;img src=a onalert=alert(1)&gt;example&#38;group=N/A"></a></td>

<td>A&lt;/&gt;&lt;img src=a onalert=alert(1)&gt;example</td>
```

Comment: Doesn't look injectable to me. What happens with a double quote in the payload? Also, it's onerror not onalert.

Comment: Sorry i mispelled the onerror lol no problem already try it with onerror

Comment: @paj28 if i use double quote the response comes like this 

&lt;script&gt;alert(&#34;test&#34;)&lt;/script&gt

Comment: That looks non-injectable to me - the app is correctly escaping that field. Move on and try more input points, other attacks, etc.

Comment: Actually i cant the entire site is using this protection in every input to deny any type of injection i just need to see if there is a way to bypass the enconding

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet